# Prestashop quantity with declination

Tags: php, class, smarty, prestashop

I did not receive any response in the official prestashop forum, I would like to ask a question.

Instead of displaying the number of product available I would like to display some lights of colour for informing the customer availability. In fact I think it is better to display "In stock", than 3 products left.

So I started to edit the `.tpl`, but I really do not know what need to be changed in order to works.

So here is the part of interest:

```
<!-- availability -->
   <p id="availability_statut"{if ($product->quantity <= 0 && !$product->available_later && $allow_oosp) OR ($product->quantity > 0 && !$product->available_now) OR !$product->available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
        <span id="availability_label">{l s='Availability:'}</span>
        <span id="availability_value"{if $product->quantity <= 0} class="warning_inline"{/if}>{if $product->quantity <= 0}{if $allow_oosp}{$product->available_later}{else}{l s='This product is no longer in stock'}{/if}{else}{$product->available_now}{/if}</span>  
   </p>
   <p id="availability_date"{if ($product->quantity > 0) OR !$product->available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE OR !isset($product->available_date) OR $product->available_date < $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'} style="display: none;"{/if}>
        <span id="availability_date_label">{l s='Availability date:'}</span>
        <span id="availability_date_value">{dateFormat date=$product->available_date full=false}</span>
   </p>
   <!-- number of item in stock -->
```

I remove that part and put the following code:

```
<p>
            {if $product->checkQty($this->id) == 0}<span><img src='images/red.gif' title='Produit en rupture de stock'> Produit en rupture de stock</span>{/if}
            {if $product->checkQty($this->id) >= 1 AND $product->checkQty($this->id) <=5}<span><img src='images/orange.gif' title='Attention : Derni&egrave;res quantit&eacute;s disponible'> Attention : Derni&egrave;res quantit&eacute;s disponible</span>{/if}
            {if $product->checkQty($this->id) > 5}<span><img src='images/green.gif' title='Produit en Stock'> Produit en stock</span>{/if}
            </p>
```

but this does not take in count the declination. When we change product declination, quantity remains the same. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by declination? is it when a user inputs certain quantity in a box in the shopping cart?

Comment: no the declination quantity is the product which is in my stock for example if I have 5 black chocolate boxes and 0 white chocolate boxes it display available for each declination when the user select

Comment: i don't see a loop iterating through multiple products/variations. I only see a single product/variation quantity. So i am still confused about what you mean.

Comment: for example in that page http://omega-nutrition.fr/100-whey-premium-muscletech-proteines-48.html I have declination vanille and chocolat. I have 5 vanille in stock 0 chocolate but for each it says "in stock available"

Comment: well the original code had `$product->quantity` but the code you wrote has a separate function called checkQty, and your passing in id, although from the look of it `$product` looks like a model already have attributes defined, so i would recheck your function

Comment: I also tried with $product->quantity but it does not change